# Result is displaying a number instead of a set of characters

Tags: c#, arrays, class, char

I'm trying to display a set of characters as one string in an array, but every time I run the program it either displays a number or zero.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wByxd.jpg
The set of values and numbers on the right is a class which I use to get information from multiple forms, and the set of codes and values on the left is for the Result form. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3UkO.jpg
The characters come from multiple forms all stored into the chr(~) value.

If you require any more information, please feel free to ask.

```
    public static string result = (chrExt + chrAgr + chrCon + chrNeu + chrOpen).ToString();

    public static string[] names = new string[20];
    public static string[] results = new string[20];
```

and

```
    string name = Data.name;
    string result = Data.result;

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main frm = new Main();
        this.Hide();
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Data.names[Data.i] = name;
        Data.results[Data.i] = result;

        Data.i = Data.i + 1;

        lstNames.Items.Clear();
        lstResults.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < Data.index; i++)
        {
            lstNames.Items.Add(Data.names[i]);
            lstResults.Items.Add(Data.results[i]);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code

```
public static int chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen;
```

to

```
public static char chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen;
```

and then I changed

```
public static string result = (chrExt + chrAgr + chrCon + chrNeu + chrOpen).ToString();
```

to

```
public static string result
    {
        get { return string.Concat(chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen); }
    }
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `chr*` variables are of type `int`. So this line

```
public static string result = (chrExt + chrAgr + chrCon + chrNeu + chrOpen).ToString();
```

**first sums up the integers** and converts the result to a `string`. You can change this to

```
public static string result = string.Empty + chrExt + chrAgr + chrCon + chrNeu + chrOpen;
```

or use `string.Concat`:

```
public static string result = string.Concat(chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen);
```

---

But this of course does not yet do what you want. You declare a `static` member and initialize it only once. At this time, all your `chr*` variables are still `0`.

From your code, I can't see when you set those variables to the desired values. But your `result` has to be computed afterwards.

One way is to declare it as a property:

```
public static string Result
{
    get { return string.Concat(chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen); }
}
```

or with C# 6 as an expression bodied member:

```
public static string Result => string.Concat(chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen);
```

Comment: @AJAlJallaf yes, because `result` is computed only once when all variables are still `0`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hello, my apologies for not adding a sample http://imgur.com/I18HTiQ this is an example of how the program chooses which character should be assigned to each char variable from different forms. And where am I supposed to add the code public static string result? the one with the get command (not sure whats the correct terminology).

Comment: @AJAlJallaf Basically you replace your `public static string result` field in your `Data` class with that. Though I think your class design is not very good, but that's too broad to address here. And please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future questions. Posting images of your code is not a good way.

Comment: Hello, thank you for all the help, I'll proceed with the code and hope for the best! and ill make sure to read the guidelines you mentioned for future questions. Good day.

Comment: One more thing, I'm very new to C# so my apologies if I made things harder than they should be.

Answer (score 1):

Character is a *number* (`Int16` to be exact), so adding up *numbers* you have a *number*. Use `String.Concat` then:

```
String test1 = ('a' + 'b').ToString();   //  195 == 97 + 98
String test2 = String.Concat('a', 'b');  // "ab" == "a" + "b"
```

In your case

```
String result = String.Concat(chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen);
```

**Edit**: As I can see form the screenshot you declare

```
public static int chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen;
```

a better choice is declare `char` as `char`, not `int`:

```
public static char chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen;
```

If you insist on `int`, then convert to `char` within `Concat`:

```
String result = String.Concat(
  (char)chrExt, (char)chrAgr, (char)chrCon, (char)chrNeu, (char)chrOpen);
```

Comment: OP shows the declaration of the `chr*` variables in the image. It's actually `int`s instead of `char`

Comment: Hello, I tried using String.Concat, this is what I got... http://imgur.com/a/e1pJP, I'm kind of lost.

Comment: @AJ Al Jallaf: why do you declare `public static int chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen; ` instead of `public static char chrExt, chrAgr, chrCon, chrNeu, chrOpen;` change `int` to `char`

Comment: Hello, my apologies i forgot to change the int to char  http://imgur.com/mscDpPa here is a result to what happened when i did that. http://imgur.com/I18HTiQ and here is an example of how the program chooses which character should be assigned to each char variable from different forms.